# Using jQuery to load another HTML page into current HTML page

Tags: html, jquery

I have a file called `navbar.html` which I want to load onto my `index.html`.
I am trying to load via jQuery, but this does not seem to be working.

Here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home | title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="hello">testing</div>
        <div id="nav-placeholder">
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#nav-placeholder').load("./navbar.html");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `navbar.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!---Create the navigation bar.-->
        <div class="top_navigation_bar">
                <span>
                    nav title
                </span>
                <a href="Projects.html">Projects</a>
                <a href="About Me.html">About Me</a>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
               
            </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. Most likely that the path to the file is wrong. also note that the HTML you load shouldn't contain another entire DOM. Just load the content you need, ie. the `.top_navigation_bar`

Comment: But I need to load the <a> tags from the navbar.html. How would I load the div containing these <a> elements?

Comment: Add the selector to the load method: `$('#nav-placeholder').load("./navbar.html .top_navigation_bar");`

Comment: There are errors in your `navbar.html` - `<div>` and `</header>` don't match. Also, what is the error?

Comment: @agrm This is still not working. (I have also fixed that tag mismatch as suggested by above)

Comment: Any help guys??

Comment: Have you checked the console yet? We can't help you with the lack of information in the question.